# Create an organic cube with circular extrusion

Tags: modeling, objects, bezier-curves, topology

I'm trying to achieve the front section of this juke box. That circular extrusion (it comes out about 3/4" or 2cm. over the keypad.) has got me stumped.  I tried joining cylinder and cube very low poly, but the bevels can't be large enough. I tried using bevel shader, I'd read that gives a good look for joining objects, but not in this case. I think curves are the way to go, but I can't quite figure it out.
[image: Front of Juke]

Answer (score 0):

You can begin with this shape:

[image]

Then begin to bevel your angles:

[image]

Extrude this part:

[image]

Bevel again:

[image]

Continue with the smaller bevels, re-work the topology, etc:

[image]